# Notification within 24 hours

Tags: java, android, notifications

I created a method to send a notification to the user named `sendNotification ()` using [`NotificationCompat.Builder` and `NotificationManager`](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification.html).

I need this notification to be posted at a fixed interval of 24 hours or even at a specific time, for example every day at **07:00 AM**, which in this case would result in the same 24 hours, which may be adjusted by the user in the future.

It seems to me that with the public class [AlarmManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) it is possible to perform this procedure, but I am not sure if I have to create a service or if it would be the service itself.

How could this notification be done within this 24-hour ?

Comment: Are you sure this question hasn't been asnwered before ?

Comment: @JonZarate I did not meet that purpose. If I met, I did not understand much.

Comment: It is possible to use the AlarmManager as you have pointed out. Make sure the alarm calls to a service that builds the notification and you're all set

Answer (score 0):

```
       public void setLocalNotification(){
                alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
                alarmIntent = new Intent(this, LocalNotificationReceiver.class);
                pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 99, alarmIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
                Log.d("TAG ","LocalNotification Start");
                alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,System.currentTimeMillis() + AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingIntent);
            }


public class LocalNotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("TUS-NOTAS ", "LocalNotification Receiver");
        Intent service1 = new Intent(context, ShowNotificationService.class);
        context.startService(service1);
    }
}


public class ShowNotificationService extends IntentService {

    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    private NotificationManager notificationManager;
    private final static String TAG = "ShowNotification";

    public ShowNotificationService()
    {
        super("ServiceNotification");
    }


    public ShowNotificationService(String name) {
        super(name);
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Context context = this.getApplicationContext();
        Uri uri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

         notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        Intent mIntent = new Intent(this, SplashActivity.class);
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,99, mIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        builder.setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name));

        builder.setVibrate(new long[] { 200, 200});
        builder.setSound(uri);

        if (Global.getStringKey(getApplicationContext(), Definitions.LANGUAGE_VALUE).equals("en"))
        {
            builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("We miss you!"));
            builder.setContentText("You have not added any notes recently.");
        }else if (Global.getStringKey(getApplicationContext(),Definitions.LANGUAGE_VALUE).equals("es"))
        {
            builder.setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText("Te extrañamos!"));
            builder.setContentText("No has agregado notas recientemente.");
        }


        builder.setAutoCancel(true);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_logo_app);

        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());

        Log.d("TUS-NOTAS"," LocalNotification Service");

    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {

    }


}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
0 0 7 1/1 * ? *
```

This is a cron statement made from http://www.cronmaker.com/. You can use this in a cron job that executes everyday at 7 am.